# node.js app with node-gyp fails to deploy on azure website

Tags: node.js, azure, node-gyp

I have set up an Azure website and I am trying to use a sample application that relies on node-gyp.

I am getting this:

```
emote: > node-expat@2.0.0 install C:\DWASFiles\Sites\node-canvas\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-salesforce\node_modules\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat
remote: > node-gyp rebuild
remote: 
remote: 
remote: C:\DWASFiles\Sites\node-canvas\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-salesforce\node_modules\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat>node "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\1.2.18\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild 
remote: Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
remote: MSBUILD : error MSB3428: Could not load the Visual C++ component "VCBuild.exe". To fix this, 1) install the .NET Framework 2.0 SDK, 2) install Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 or 3) add the location of the component to the system path if it is installed elsewhere.  [C:\DWASFiles\Sites\node-canvas\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-salesforce\node_modules\xml2json\node_modules\node-expat\build\binding.sln]
remote: gypnpm ERR! node-expat@2.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
remote: npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
remote: npm ERR! 
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the node-expat@2.0.0 install script.
remote: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-expat package,
remote: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote: npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
remote: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
remote: npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-expat
remote: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: 
remote: npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
remote: npm ERR! command "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\0.8.19\\node.exe" "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\1.2.18\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--production"
remote: npm ERR! cwd C:\DWASFiles\Sites\node-canvas\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot
remote: npm ERR! node -v v0.8.19
remote: npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm
remote: 
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed, please check log for further details.
To https://mike@node-canvas.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/node-canvas.git
   ef20ef4..147856f  master -> master
```

Do people have a graceful resolution to this or do I need to spin up a linux VM and deploy the application like that?

Comment: Were you able to publish your project to Azure? I'm having the same problem using the node-canvas module

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Limitation of web sites. See the native modules section of http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/nodejs-use-node-modules-azure-apps/.

The workaround/resolution is to install all the modules on a Windows dev box and include node_modules as part of the git deployment.

Comment: that is not really a good solution, any updates since Oct 2013?

Comment: As per [#1076](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1076) it should be working correctly. An alternative you can use is [VSTS Hosted Build](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/apps/node/nodejs-to-azure) which has all the required dependencies (tested and it works perfect).

Comment: Remeber to enable python on the app service/web site you are installing on :)

Comment: It does work now, but not on Free/Shared sites.
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps-formerly-websites/suggestions/6573329-support-for-node-gyp-in-nodejs-applications

Answer (score 6):

I recently successfully deployed a Node.js app/ Sails app running as an Azure web app that relies on Grunt and therefore needs support for node-gyp as well. At first I struggled with getting node-gyp to run on continuous deployment **without including the node_modules** folder but finally I succeded with a what you would hopefully call "graceful resolution".
The steps that were necessary for me are:

1. Make sure you use a somewhat up to date version of Node and NPM (as far as Azure allows you to do so: . In my case I used node 5.4.0 and npm 3.3.12. Deploying on Azure there is two ways I know of to do this:

   - **Application settings**: WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION 5.4.0 (or whatever)
   - **Package.json** file: Include the following:

     ```
     "engines": {    
         "node": "5.4.0",    
         "npm": "3.3.12"  
     },
     ```
2. Change the settings in the **config/env/production.js** file to give grunt more time to uglify or whatever. The default value of 20s seems to be too low for a lot of applications out there, however there might be better ways to solve this: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/2691 
   I put:

   ```
   hookTimeout: 60000, // 60 seconds
   ```
3. I used a **.deployment** and **deploy.cmd** / deploy.sh (depending on your system) file to customize the deployment on the Azure platform. The guide I used was: http://www.cptloadtest.com/2013/12/03/Git-And-Grunt-Deploy-To-Windows-Azure.aspx

   **EDIT:** looks like my original command to run Grunt from deploy.cmd is incorrect, I am not familiar with bash scripts, sorry. I ended up using the script from this question with some modifications: [Deploying a NodeJS App to Azure Websites fails on installing NPM packages from pagages.json from deploy.cmd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26217222/deploying-a-nodejs-app-to-azure-websites-fails-on-installing-npm-packages-from-p) 
    Using this script my grunt task runs on deployment. Here are the modified parts of my script. 
    **deploy.cmd:**

   ```
   :: Setup
   :: -----        

   :: ... some default parts omitted

   IF NOT DEFINED GRUNT_CMD (
     :: Install grunt
     echo Installing Grunt
     call npm --registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/" install grunt-cli
     IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

     :: Locally just running "grunt" would also work
   SET GRUNT_CMD=node "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\node_modules\grunt-cli\bin\grunt"
   )

   goto Deployment

   :: Utility Functions
   :: -----------------

   :SelectNodeVersion

   :: ... some default parts omitted

   ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
   :Deployment
   echo Handling node.js deployment.
   echo %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%

   echo 1. Select node version
   call :SelectNodeVersion

   echo 2. Install npm packages dev dependencies
   IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\package.json" (
     pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%"
     echo Cleaning NPM cache.
     call !NPM_CMD! cache clean
     call !NPM_CMD! install --development
     IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
     popd
   )        

   echo 4. Run grunt prod task
   pushd %DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%
   call !GRUNT_CMD! --no-color prod
   IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
   popd

   echo 5. KuduSync
   IF /I "%IN_PLACE_DEPLOYMENT%" NEQ "1" (
     call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
     IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
   )

   echo 6. Install npm packages production
   IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%\package.json" (
     pushd %DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%
     call !NPM_CMD! install --production
     IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
     popd
   )
   ```
4. I then ran into this error: [ENOTSUP using Grunt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199739/enotup-using-grunt) which was thankfully recently solved :) 
   All that was left for me to do was to change the for deploy.sh given syntax to work in my deploy.cmd. So **before** running grunt from **deploy.cmd** I included:

   ```
   echo 3. Update erroneous glob dependency in Grunt 
   pushd "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\node_modules\grunt"
   call :ExecuteCmd !NPM_CMD! install glob@^6.0.4 --save
   IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error
   popd
   ```

I hope this helps some of you out there, although I am aware, that some of the issues I faced might be solved using up to date versions of node and npm. But since Azure does not out of the box provide the latest versions this might still be helpful for some of you.

**EDIT:**

Regarding:

1. Node version choice:

   I tried to select the node version by only setting it in Package.json without changing the default settings in the Application settings (default version: 4.2.3) and I still got the following error:

   ```
   Node.js versions available on the platform are: 0.6.20, 0.8.2, 0.8.19, 0.8.26, 0.8.27, 0.8.28, 0.10.5, 0.10.18, 0.10.21, 0.10.24, 0.10.26, 0.10.28, 0.10.29, 0.10.31, 0.10.32, 0.10.40, 0.12.0, 0.12.2, 0.12.3, 0.12.6, 4.0.0, 4.1.0, 4.1.2, 4.2.1, 4.2.2, 4.2.3, 4.2.4, 5.0.0, 5.1.1, 5.3.0, 5.4.0, 5.5.0.
   Selected node.js version 5.4.0. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
   Selected npm version 3.3.12
   Updating iisnode.yml at D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode.yml
   3. Install npm packages
   npm WARN deprecated lodash@0.9.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
   npm WARN deprecated grunt-lib-contrib@0.7.1: DEPRECATED. See readme: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-lib-contrib
   npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<2.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^3.0.0
   > sails@0.11.4 preinstall D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\.staging\sails-bbe9b0ace9f7789c8522238af14fe27a
   > node ./lib/preinstall_npmcheck.js

   Sails.js Installation: Checking npm-version successful
   npm WARN prefer global grunt-cli@0.1.13 should be installed with -g

   > fibers@1.0.8 install D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
   > node build.js || nodejs build.js


   D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "c:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.3.12\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild --release )  else (node  rebuild --release ) 
   Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
     fibers.cc
     coroutine.cc
   ..\src\fibers.cc : fatal error C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation [D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
   ..\src\coroutine.cc : fatal error C1902: Program database manager mismatch; please check your installation [D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers\build\fibers.vcxproj]
   gyp ERR! build error 
   gyp ERR! stack Error: `msbuild` failed with exit code: 1
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (c:\Program Files (x86)\npm\3.3.12\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:270:23)
   gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
   gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
   gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
   gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
   gyp ERR! command "D:\\Program Files (x86)\\nodejs\\4.2.3\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files (x86)\\npm\\3.3.12\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
   gyp ERR! cwd D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\fibers
   gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.3
   gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
   Build failed
   ```

   Like you can see it first states:

   ```
   Selected node.js version 5.4.0. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
   ```

   according to the Package.json file. 
    However, later on in the error message this seems to have changed:

   ```
   gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.3
   ```

   To me it is not obvious why this error occurs since the version in the Package.json file should be overwriting the default in the Application settings. So to be sure just set both settings to a high enough version (not sure when the node-gyp problem was solved, but 5.4.0 seems to be working fine!).

Comment: Holy crap... this gave me the answer I needed. "Use Nuget" - I had to update the nuget in a recent build from 5 to 5.8... I also, apparently, needed to "Use Node 10x". Amazing all the small changes I needed to make to a 'default' install that should just work.