# ENOTSUP using Grunt

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-concat, azure-deployment

I'm using Grunt to minify and concatenate files for an AngularJS web application.  Our source is on a file share and I'm connecting to it via a mapped drive.  Whenever Grunt runs over my source directory, I get an error on one of my concat tasks.  The error is "ENOTSUP, operation not supported on socket".  If I copy the source, local, Grunt runs, fine.  For the sake of our source control, I need Grunt to watch and run over the mapped drive.  The concat task uses grunt-contrib-concat.  I've tried reinstalling Node and rolling back grunt-contrib-concat to version 0.4.0.  That didn't work.  Any help/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

The code in Grunt that gives the error is:

```
  jscustom: {
            src: ['src/js/*.js', 'src/js/**/*.js', 'build/temp/templates.js'],
            dest: 'build/temp/custom.js'
}
```

If I remove "'src/js/**/*.js'," from the code, above, and excute my Grunt task, the ENOTSUP error does not occur.  I need to use those wild cards to include all directories and files.

Comment: I've, also, attempted to connect to the share with an mklink /D.  That gives me the same error.

Comment: By the way; would you be so kind to add 'azure-deployment' tag to this question? Perhaps this might be usefull to others as well...

Comment: @mrcl I've added the tag.  Thanks, again.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We've ran into this problem when we started deploying to Azure.

The problem is most likely caused by a bug in [glob](https://www.npmjs.com/package/glob) (on which Grunt has an dependency).

This bug is long since been fixed (see [github issue 205](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob/issues/205)), but unfortunately the latest stable release on NPM is 0.4.5 (published two years ago) - which has an dependency on glob version 3.1.21 (current version is 6.0.4).

So fixes for this are either:

a) get grunt by cloning from github instead of using npm

or

b) after npm install, navigate to `/node_modules/grunt` and execute an `npm install glob@^6.0.4 --save` to upgrade the glob dependency of the installed grunt version.

In your deploy.sh, the npm install may look like this:

```
eval $NPM_CMD install
```

You'll want to add the following right after it

```
pushd ./node_modules/grunt
eval $NPM_CMD install glob@^6.0.4 --save
popd
```

Note; changing the /**/ to /*/ gets rid of the error, but then you give up 
the recursive copy.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've updated glob in grunt and this appears to be working!

Comment: You're welcome -- I was in doubt whether adding this answer would help anyone, but I'm glad I've taken the time since apparently it did. :)

Comment: I have a shared node instance at Azure and cannot run command line queries. How can I fix this? I am using latest version of grunt & glob.

Comment: hi @Teomanshipahi, do you mean you don't have sufficient rights to get to a console? Or that you don't know how? If you add .scm. between you instance name and azurewebsites.net in the url (e.g. https://mysite.scm.azurewebsites.net/), you ought te get access to Kudu service site - and there you can access the debug console.

Comment: @mrcl this helps a lot. Thanks for sharing that information.

Comment: Thanks @mrcl I also had to add this to my general deploy.cmd for Azure App Service because my passport strategies weren't loading in my yeoman meanjs template site. Kept getting endless redirects to /server-error because I had added optional basic authentication.

Comment: @mrcl Thank-you! You saved me at least an hour of debugging and trying possible solutions.

Comment: Woot! Thank you very much. This is fixing it. Had the issue on a fresh Windows 10 installation. Just a note: The same error did not happened on my previous windows 7 system.