# ENOTUP warning using grunt in Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, gruntjs, azure-web-app-service

In a simple copy task in Azure Werservice I get that warning that stop my build process

*Warning: ENOTSUP: operation not supported on socket, scandir*

My copy task config

```
  dist: {
   nonull: true,
   files: [{
    expand: true,
    src: [
      '<%= app.dir %>/*.js',
      '<%= app.dir %>/dev/*.js',
      '<%= app.dir %>/models/*.js',
      '<%= app.dir %>/src/*.js',
      'build/*/*',
      'public/*/*',
      'IISNode.yml',
      'server.js',
    ],
    dest: '<%= dist.tmp %>',
  }]
```

}

Node version : 5.1.1

How can i fix this problem? Any help or suggestion would be very appreciated

Comment: This has been answered a little more thoroughly in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199739/enotsup-using-grunt

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I just found that maybe you need to remove `iisnode.yml` from the `src` list. As issnode.yml is not the javascript script which is a configuration file for iisnode, and which will raise a grunt warning and throw an exception on my side. But I haven't reproduced your issue.

So if it is convenient of you to provide your project repo or the complete gruntfile content, it will be a great helpful for us to reproduce your issue.

Comment: Without iisnode.yml i have the same error. I replaced "/*/*" with the list of all sub-directories and work fine :|

Comment: Anyway, congratulations. As you can generate a simple answer to yourself if you are willing to, and which will give hints to those who occurs the similar issue with you.